# Reason for phase change in the electric field oscillations, not the magnetic field oscillations?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, reflection

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_phase_change) states that when an EM wave undergoes reflection, there is a phase change only in the electric field oscillations, not the magnetic field oscillations. It also suggests that the opposite is true when reflection occurs at a lower refractive index interface. Why would this be the case? What is the mechanism that addresses these problems (I tried figuring it out but it's quite difficult since there is no given analogy of components of an EM wave in mechanical waves on a string)